# While or loop where on or condition is addressed but the other is not?

Tags: java

I am programming a simulation of Monopoly and I wanted to know if there is a way to address a variable if it is over a number but not the other variable?

```
while (i<=200){
        while(Player1.space<41 || Player2.space<41){    
            roll();
            Player1.space=Player1.space+roll();
            System.out.println("Player1 "+Player1.space);
            i++;

            roll();
            Player2.space=Player2.space+roll();
            System.out.println("Player2 "+Player2.space);
            i++;
        }
        //So here I want to reset the variable that  reached 41 back to one.
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have to copy a block of code multiple times, you may want to look into creating a method. However, couldn't you just check `if(Player1.space == 41) Player1.space = 0; else Player2.space = 0;`

Comment: Your inner while will not break until **both** players reach 41.

Comment: @Hiyapiwi. Did my answer help? If so please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. I notice you have asked several questions since joining, but [not marked any of the answers as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3839078+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ano) - you should get into the habit of accepting the best answer to your problem.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Sorry :( @AndyBrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
int moveTo = Player1.space + roll();
Player1.space = moveTo > 40 ? moveTo - 40 : moveTo;
```

This assumes that your `space` numbering starts at 1 (which it seems to if you say that `40` is a valid space, and from your comment that you want to "reset the variable that  reached 41 back to one").

You then have no more need for the inner while loop, so you just need

```
while (i <= 200) {
  int moveTo = Player1.space + roll();
  Player1.space = moveTo > 40 ? moveTo - 40 : moveTo;
  ...
```

It gets shorter still with the modulus operator (divide by `40` and use the remainder as your output):

```
Player1.space = (Player1.space + roll()) % 40;
```

This works really well if your space numbering starts at 0, but can be adjusted if it starts at 1 as follows:

```
Player1.space = 1 + ((Player1.space + roll() - 1) % 40);
```

You can see the difference between the two with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int moveTo = 0; moveTo < 50; moveTo++) {
        int space = moveTo > 40 ? moveTo - 40 : moveTo;
        System.out.println("" + moveTo + " " + space);
    }
    for (int moveTo = 0; moveTo < 50; moveTo++) {
        int space = moveTo % 40;
        System.out.println("" + moveTo + " " + space);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it should be noted that in implementing this, OP should get rid of the inner `while` loop or it will never exit.